# KeyError 'metrics' when trying to train a model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I was working off some github code where I'm training a model to recognize laughter.  This particular bit of code is giving me problems:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Flatten

lr_model = Sequential()
# lr_model.add(keras.Input((None, 128)))
lr_model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(10, 128)))
lr_model.add(Flatten())
lr_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
lr_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size=32

CV_frac = 0.1
train_gen = data_generator(batch_size,'../Data/bal_laugh_speech_subset.tfrecord', 0, 1-CV_frac)
val_gen = data_generator(128,'../Data/bal_laugh_speech_subset.tfrecord', 1-CV_frac, 1)

rec_len = 18768

lr_h = lr_model.fit_generator(train_gen,steps_per_epoch=int(rec_len*(1-CV_frac))//batch_size, epochs=100, 
                       validation_data=val_gen, validation_steps=int(rec_len*CV_frac)//128,
                       verbose=0, callbacks=[TQDMNotebookCallback()])
```

It gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-9eced074de11> in <module>
      7 rec_len = 18768
      8 
----> 9 lr_h = lr_model.fit_generator(train_gen,steps_per_epoch=int(rec_len*(1-CV_frac))//batch_size, epochs=100, 
     10                        validation_data=val_gen, validation_steps=int(rec_len*CV_frac)//128,
     11                        verbose=0, callbacks=[TQDMNotebookCallback()])

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1845                   'will be removed in a future version. '
   1846                   'Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.')
-> 1847     return self.fit(
   1848         generator,
   1849         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1103               logs = tmp_logs  # No error, now safe to assign to logs.
   1104               end_step = step + data_handler.step_increment
-> 1105               callbacks.on_train_batch_end(end_step, logs)
   1106               if self.stop_training:
   1107                 break

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
    452     """
    453     if self._should_call_train_batch_hooks:
--> 454       self._call_batch_hook(ModeKeys.TRAIN, 'end', batch, logs=logs)
    455 
    456   def on_test_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _call_batch_hook(self, mode, hook, batch, logs)
    294       self._call_batch_begin_hook(mode, batch, logs)
    295     elif hook == 'end':
--> 296       self._call_batch_end_hook(mode, batch, logs)
    297     else:
    298       raise ValueError('Unrecognized hook: {}'.format(hook))

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _call_batch_end_hook(self, mode, batch, logs)
    314       self._batch_times.append(batch_time)
    315 
--> 316     self._call_batch_hook_helper(hook_name, batch, logs)
    317 
    318     if len(self._batch_times) >= self._num_batches_for_timing_check:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _call_batch_hook_helper(self, hook_name, batch, logs)
    358         if numpy_logs is None:  # Only convert once.
    359           numpy_logs = tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
--> 360         hook(batch, numpy_logs)
    361 
    362     if self._check_timing:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
    708     """
    709     # For backwards compatibility.
--> 710     self.on_batch_end(batch, logs=logs)
    711 
    712   @doc_controls.for_subclass_implementers

~/env/py385/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_tqdm/tqdm_callback.py in on_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
    115         self.inner_count += update
    116         if self.inner_count < self.inner_total:
--> 117             self.append_logs(logs)
    118             metrics = self.format_metrics(self.running_logs)
    119             desc = self.inner_description_update.format(epoch=self.epoch, metrics=metrics)

~/env/py385/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_tqdm/tqdm_callback.py in append_logs(self, logs)
    134 
    135     def append_logs(self, logs):
--> 136         metrics = self.params['metrics']
    137         for metric, value in six.iteritems(logs):
    138             if metric in metrics:

KeyError: 'metrics'
```

All the other KeyError 'metrics' problems I've googled have to do with something else called livelossplot.  Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: try `model.fit()` instead of `model.fit_generator()` --> it's deprecated

Comment: @NicolasGervais  you're right!  But unfortunately even after I use `model.fit()` I get the exact same error which points to line 136.  Any other ideas?

Comment: welp, I got rid of the `callbacks=[TQDMNotebookCallback()]` and it seems to be working.  I just need to satisfy the curiosity of what that particular parameter is...it seems like it's more cosmetic than anything